# Stripe with multi step form user registration

Tags: stripe-payments

So I started playing with stripe yesterday and so far so good. I have a three step registration form, first is personal info (name), second one is password and email and third tab is for payment (monthly subscription). My logic is that if payment succeeded, then create the account on my end, if it did not, then throw the error.

So far so good- my logic works, but I have few issues. As I read [this documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/tutorial) then I should store the customer ID in database for later use and checking if the subscription is active or not. In my `function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {}` when I `console.log(response)` I see the token code and card information, but I never see the customer object.

[image]
Here comes few questions:

1. Is my method and logic safe what I described in the first paragraph?
2. How can I get the customer object so I could insert the id and corresponding data into the database during the registration process?

### JS

```
   function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {

       // Grab the form:
       var $form = $("#registrationForm"),
           formData = new FormData(),
           params = $form.serializeArray();

       if (response.error) { // Problem!

           // Show the errors on the form:
           console.log(response.error.message);
           $form.find('#btn-signup').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission

       } else { // Token was created!

           // Get the token ID:
           var token = response.id;
           console.log(token);
           console.log(response);

           // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
           $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token));

           // Submit the form:
           $.ajax({
               url: $form.attr('action'),
               type: 'POST',
               data: $form.serialize(),
               cache: false,
               success: function(data) {
                   $("#formAlert").empty();
                   console.log(data);

                   var items = '';
                   $.each(data.status, function(key, val) {
                       items += '<li>' + val + '</li>';
                       $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
                   });

                   $("#registerAlerts").append(items);
               },
               error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data) {
                   $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
                   console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data);

               }
           });
       }
   }

   $("#btn-signup").on("click", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(".se-pre-con").show();

       var $form = $("#registrationForm");

       // Request a token from Stripe:
       Stripe.card.createToken({
           number: $('.card-number').val(),
           cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
           exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
           exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
       }, stripeResponseHandler);

   });
```

### PHP

```
    <?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
require_once 'class.user.php';

require_once ('../plugins/stripe/init.php');

$errors = 0;

if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
    $errors++;
    $errors_query["status"][] = 'User exists';
    }

if ($errors == 0)
    {
    try
        {
        $customer = StripeCustomer::create(array(
            'email' => $_POST['formEmail'],
            'source' => $token,
            'plan' => '123456789',
            "description" => "Subscription for user " . $uFirstname
        ));
        if ($reg_user->register($email, $upass, $code, $utype, $uFirstname, $uLastname, $termAndAgreement))
            {
            $user_id = $reg_user->lasdID();
            $family_files = $reg_user->runQuery("INSERT into user_files (user_id, file_type, file_size, file_name, file_new_name, file_path, file_cat, file_folder, date_created) VALUES (:user_id, 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'profilePicture', 'profilePicture', NOW())");
            $family_files->bindparam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $family_files->execute();
            }
          else
            {
            $errors++;
            $errors_query["status"][] = 'error';
            }
        }

    catch(Exception $e)
        {
        $errors++;
        $errors_query["status"][] = 'Error with payment';
        $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

if ($errors > 0)
    {
    echo json_encode($errors_query);
    exit();
    }
  else
    {
    $errors_query["status"][] = 'user_welcome';
    echo json_encode($errors_query);
    exit();
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using custom Stripe Payment form is completely safe. Stripe also wrote in their documentation about it and as long as you are using Stripe.js it is safe.

When you register any user using the credit card then it always returns a Stripe token. It will not return the customer id nither customer is created at this time so for this you have to call the create customer API and pass the above token in it and It will return customer object using customer Id.

you can read about stripe create customer API [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer)